# String value is not have mutable behaviour (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mutable

I converting my String value to Double shows in below code .In final variable i am getting string value i.e ex - 1435.76 But while i am converting into Double value shows nill. Please help me to get rid into this .Thanks in advance

```
self.cart = result.value(forKey: "cart") as! NSMutableArray
self.totalsDic = result.value(forKey: "totals") as! NSMutableDictionary
print(self.totalsDic)
// print(self.cart)

let total = self.totalsDic.object(forKey: "total") as! NSMutableDictionary
let final = total.object(forKey: "total") as? String
// final = final?.replacingOccurrences(of: "Rs.", with: "")


let myDouble1 = NumberFormatter().number(from: final!)?.doubleValue
print("My double: \(String(describing: myDouble))")
let myDouble2 = Double(final!)
```

Comment: `Double(final!)` returns nil only if final is nil or contains a string which cant be converted to Double. Hence your best bet is to use `.doubleValue` which will make sure that if it fails to convert string to Double falls to safe value of 0. Finally rather than using ! (Force unwrap) use `if let` or `guard let` depending on your need

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari, as i mention final has value and .doublevalue also returning nill and how can i check that string is mutable or immutable.

Comment: two things 1. How will string is mutable or immutable affects the conversion of String to Double??? 2. You have declared final as let. How do you expect it to be mutable ? Doesn't let mean its a immutable string ??

Comment: @SandeepBhandari ,Thanks for your help , Actually i test it now , It convert the value below 1000 as it print Optional(963.837655277). it not converting the value above 1000 . I don't know why??

Comment: Cant be!! Double has much larger range then 1000 I tested with 1234.56 it works fine. So there is something else going wrong